# Transform a 3-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
array(3) {
    ["FL_1"] => array(3) {
        ["MIC_1"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_4"] => float(7)
        }
        ["MIC_13"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_16"] => float(4)
        }
        ["MIC_6"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_74"] => float(4)
        }
    }
    ["FL_2"] => array(2) {
        ["MIC_1"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_5"] => float(4)
        }
        ["MIC_13"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_17"] => float(4)
        }
        ["MIC_6"] > array(1) {
            ["SP_75"] => float(4)
        }
    }
    ["FL_3"] => array(2) {
        ["MIC_1"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_5"] => float(89)
        }
        ["MIC_13"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_18"] => float(1)
        }
        ["MIC_6"] > array(1) {
            ["SP_78"] => float(21)
        }
    }
}
```

For each `FL_X`, I need to keep only one `MIC_X` that follow the conditions below :

> 1- This `MIC_X` needs to be the same for each `FL_X`
>   2- This `MIC_X` needs to have the lowest possible `SP_X`value

**From this example I need to get the following array**

```
array(3) {
    ["FL_1"] => array(1) {
        ["MIC_13"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_16"] => float(4)
        }
    }
    ["FL_2"] => array(1) {
        ["MIC_13"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_17"] => float(6)
        }
    }
    ["FL_3"] => array(1) {
        ["MIC_13"] => array(1) {
            ["SP_18"] => float(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.
Thank you !

Comment: Your question isn't 100% clear. What if the lowest `SP_X` value occurs on a `MIC_X` value which doesn't exist in all `FL_X` arrays?

Comment: you want to loop the array, find the second level with the same key value of each parent level, then get the lowest level of the third levels float value, correct?

Comment: @Nick I edited my question, indeed the same ```MIC_X```exist for all ```FL_X```

Comment: @dalelandry No, I need to keep the ```MIC_X``` with the lowest float value score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. It uses [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to find the `SP_X` key associated with the minimum `SP_X` value, then it traverses the array to find the `MIC_X` key associated with that `SP_X` key and value, and finally it uses [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to extract only those `MIC_X` key values from the original array:

// find the minimum SP_X value and its key

```
$min_sp = PHP_INT_MAX;
$min_key = '';
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($v, $k) use (&$min_sp, &$min_key) {
    if ($v < $min_sp) {
        $min_sp = $v;
        $min_key = $k;
    } 
});

// find the MIC_X key corresponding to the min SP_X value
$mic_key = '';
foreach ($array as $fl) {
    foreach ($fl as $mic => $sp) {
        if (isset($sp[$min_key]) && $sp[$min_key] == $min_sp) {
            $mic_key = $mic;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}

// filter the array to get all the MIC_X values
$out = array_map(function ($fl) use ($mic_key) {
    return array_filter($fl, function ($mic) use ($mic_key) {
        return $mic == $mic_key;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}, $array);

print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [FL_1] => Array
        (
            [MIC_13] => Array
                (
                    [SP_16] => 4
                )
        )
    [FL_2] => Array
        (
            [MIC_13] => Array
                (
                    [SP_17] => 4
                )
        )
    [FL_3] => Array
        (
            [MIC_13] => Array
                (
                    [SP_18] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/pIoMK)

Comment: Thank you very much Nick, this is perfect !

Comment: A subsidiary question would be : based on the same array, how to get an array with the ```MIC_X``` ordered relative to their ```SP_X``` global score (the best ```MIC_X``` would have the lowest ```SP_X``` score) ?

Comment: Do the arrays only have one `SP_X` value?

Comment: Yes the arrays have only one ```SP_X``` value

Comment: `$m = array_column($out, $mic_key); array_multisort($m, $out);` might do the job...